# C# get/set solution

Tags: c#, class, get, set

To give some background I'm trying to solve the Project Euler [Problem 54](https://projecteuler.net/problem=54) involving poker hands. Though there's infinite approaches to this. What I would like to do is enumerate through a list of strings, for example:
{ "8C", "TS", "KC", "9H", "4S" };

I would like to "get" an instance of class card with properties value, and suit, for each respective string. I've not yet utilized get/set so maybe there is an obvious approach to this I'm missing.

Ultimately I would like to have a list of objects type Card, I don't mind building all the card's ahead of time, such that "2H" returns an instance of type Card where suit = Hearts, and value = 2, for example.

I know this code is wrong, but it should give an idea of what I'm trying to do. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
class Card
{
    public string suit;
    public int value;
    public string cardname
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (cardname == "2H") Card TwoH = new Card();
                TwoH.suit = "Hearts"
                TwoH.value = 2;
                return TwoH; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you return if `cardname != "2h"` ? Moreover, is `Card` a `String` ?

Comment: It's not very clear what your question is. You want to better design for a card deck? Google it.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please clarify.

Comment: @Ofiris: since there are no {} the code always returns the 2 of hearts

Comment: Clarification, in the main method, I want to enumerate through a List of strings, when the string is "2H" I want to call a method that returns a an instance of type Card where the suit is Hearts, and the value is 2. I will build a list of type Card, then evaluate the hand based on the list of type Card, not the list of strings.

Comment: I would validate it to make sure that it's 2 chars and they are both ok. Break up the string into "2" and "H" and switch on those instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
public class Card
{
    public string Suit { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static Card FromString(string s)
    {
        if (s == "2H") return new Card() { Suit = "Hearts", Value = 2 };
        else if (s == "....")
        ...
        else return null;
    }
}
```

I have converted your `suit` and `value` field into properties and instead of some getter method which in your case wouldn't work I have added a static method.

You can use it like this `Card card2H = Card.FromString("2H");`

Comment: Rather than checking against 52 strings, I'd consider parsing out the suit & value -- `string suit = s.Substring(s.Length - 1); int.TryParse(s.Substring(0,s.Length-1), out value); return new Card {Suit = GetSuitEnum(suit), Value = value);`. I'd use an Enum for the suit and have GetSuitEnum take the single-character string and return the enum value.

Comment: Yes, of course. I wanted to keep the code close to that of the in the original post. But parsing is the far better way.

Comment: I think you need a char or string for the value as well, for face cards.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make a constructor that fills suit and value based on a string parameter

```
public Card(string name)
{
    switch(name)
    {
        case "2H":
            this.suit = "Hearts";
            this.value = 2;
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the exact solution you seem to be asking for but if the values you'll be getting (eg 2H, 3C etc) are all 2 characters long, then you can try this:

```
public class Card
{
    public string suit { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }

    public static Card GetCard(string cardName)
    {
        string tmpSuit;
        int tmpValue;
        char[] cardNameParts = cardName.ToCharArray();
        switch(charNameParts[0])
        {
            case "A":
                tmpValue = 1;
                break;
            case "2":
                tmpValue = 2;
                break;
            ...
        }


        switch(charNameParts[1])
        {
            case "H":
                tmpSuit= "Hearts";
                break;
            case "C":
                tmpSuit= "Clubs";
                break;
            ...
        }
        return new Card() { suit = tmpSuit, value = tmpValue };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use two `switch` statements, first

```
switch (cardname[0])
{
    ...
}
```

then

```
switch (cardname[1])
{
    ...
}
```

Before that, check that `cardname.Length == 2`. In each `switch`, have a `default` section where you throw an exception in case the `char` value doesn't make sense.